# Ajax и json parseerror

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, маршрутизация

Дан скрипт js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#products').on('click','.addCart',function()
    {
        var id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/shop/web/add_cart?id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() {
                alert("Hi");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });


});
```

По идее после нажатия на элемент с классом `.addCart`  должно вывестись `alert;`
при том что этот `url '/shop/web/add_cart?id=' + id` контроллер обработал  запрос успешно, что можно увидеть обновив страницу, но мне нужен **success** аякса, а он не отрабатывает, что это может быть?

Вот так работаю с json:

```
echo json_encode($resData);
```

Comment: добавите после success,  error: function (err) {
           console.log(err)
        },

Comment: Ответ не соответствует условиям, которые ожидает ajax. Как вы поняли что работает контроллер ? Добавился товар ?, а ответ контроллер какой вернул ? Код ответа 2хх ? В ответе `json` (т.к. у Вас указан json тип) ? Я например пользуюсь Fiddler или Postman, что бы промониторить, что в ответе код, заголовки и само тело как мне нужно. Ну и error отлавливайте, и смотрите на ошибку

Comment: Да контроллер добавил товар, что можно увидеть после обновления страницы, в инструментах разработчика хром никаких ошибок не вылазит, в phpstorm так же

Comment: Только заголовок вопроса и его содержание ну вот прям совсем не совпадают. Я бы поправил, пока минусов не нахватали

Comment: добавьте еще php обработчик и html разметку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что почему-то ajax захватывает все что есть на странице и если на странице  не только json, а и тэги html , то он не будет работать, то есть он не может выбрать из файла именно json, приходится чистить буфер страницы *ob_start();* *ob_end_clean();*

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products').on('click','.addCart',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/shop/web/add_cart?id=' + this.id, // точно this.id ???
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `точно this.id ???` - нет не точно, ибо ваш `this.id` будет совсем в другой области, нежели был у ТС

Comment: Предполагаю, там должно быть либо $(this).attr('id'), либо $(this).data('id');

Comment: да, точно this.id, выводит теперь  Unexpected token , parserror

Comment: id точно тот который мне надо, ибо после обновления страницы нужны й мне товар не добавился бы

Comment: @DenisStepanyuk после обновления страницы не мог бы добавиться товар с тем id, т.к. при перезагрузке событие click не сработало бы в принципе и запрос не отправился. Это было бы слишком магично

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Ну мне виднее что добавляется тот id или не тот, + перед ajax  alertom выводит нужный мне id

Comment: @newbie67, стоит написать, чем именно код в ответе отличается от кода в вопросе и почему

Comment: @DenisStepanyuk, _выводит теперь Unexpected token_ - попробуй вместо `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` -> `console.log(data)`. Скорее всего `data` - уже объект и его не нужно дополнительно обрабатывать с помощью JSON.parse

Comment: @ Grundy Без указания **dataType: "json"**, в **"data"** записывается вся страница html обработчика, а если указываю dataType то ошибку выбивает **unexpected token json**